# How can I display the absolute path in bash prompt?

Tags: bash, path, prompt

I currently have my bash `PS1` set to something like this:

```
PS1="\[\`if [[ \$? = "0" ]]; then echo '\e[32m\h\e[0m'; else echo '\e[31m\h\e[0m' ; fi\`:\w\n\$ "
```

How can I make it show the absolute path instead of the relative one (e.g. `/home/dave/dir` instead of `~/dir`)?

Comment: `/home/dave/dir` and `~/dir` are both absolute paths, the second uses an abbreviation for your home directory. A relative path is a path that is *relative* to your current directory (e.g. `../dir`) rather than starting at root (`/`).

Comment: p.s. Nice use of color to indicate exit status of previous command. Probably the first use of color in a prompt that I've liked.

Comment: @Doug Harris: Thanks for the correction. I like this coloring, too. Don't remember where I first saw it (perhaps in some previous SU post?)

Comment: `\u@\H[\w]:~\$` makes `user@host[~/path]:~$`

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Just replace `\w` with `\$PWD`:

```
PS1="\[\`if [[ \$? = "0" ]]; then echo '\e[32m\h\e[0m'; else echo '\e[31m\h\e[0m' ; fi\`:\$PWD\n\$ "
```

Anyway if you mind a little tip, I'd write something like:

```
PS1='\[`[ $? = 0 ] && X=2 || X=1; tput setaf $X`\]\h\[`tput sgr0`\]:$PWD\n\$ '
```

Comment: I thought of this, too, but the `$PWD` is evaluated at the time of the assignment to `PS1`, not on each call. *However*, if you escape the dollar sign, it will work -- `\$PWD`. With this, the dollar sign is a dollar sign at time of assignment and the variable evaluation happens on each prompt.  +1 to you.

Comment: Right, missed that \, I usually work with single quotes if it's possible. Thanks.

Comment: +1 Thanks! could you please explain the magic in your beautiful bash line (the 'tip' one)?

Comment: Sure. I used tput (see man tput for more info) to change the colors rather than write the control characters directly, for readability and portability (?). Also I removed double quotes and back slashes by using single quotes. Finally by using a variable I avoided some redundancy.

Comment: That is very clever way to modify the command prompt. It shows the full path above actual prompt. Can be useful

Answer (score 40):

Put in your home `.bashrc`

```
PS1='\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

Comment: The key here is `\w` gives the full path while `\W` gives only the directory. See ["Bash Prompt Escape Sequences"](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/bash-prompt-escape-sequences.html)

Answer (score 4):

Run `pwd` instead of using `\W`.

Simple version:

```
export PS1="\`pwd\` $ "
```

Using this in your code:

```
export PS1="\[\`if [[ \$? = "0" ]]; then echo '\e[32m\h\e[0m'; else echo '\e[31m\h\e[0m' ; fi\`:\`pwd\`\n\$ "
```

Comment: minor point: per google's bash style guide, prefer $(pwd) to backticks because backticks require escaping when nesting and $() doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

in bash's ps1; -W should be relative, and -w absolute, so in the above you should already have the absolute ?!

http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt

Comment: I think you're confusing absolute|relative with full|current_dir. `W` shows only the current directory name, `w` shows the full path, but still uses relative paths.

Comment: was the terminology in the url, not mine :)

Answer (score 0):

Humm ~/dir is an absolute path but using a "shortcut". For instance, if you do `cd /usr/local` your prompt will most probably display the full path of /usr/local.
So anyway, you have already a full path :-)

But probably your correct question is how to display the full path without any shortcuts like ~?

However, I don't know an answer for that one and looking at the man, it does seem to have one (at least documented).